# Двоеточие в параметрах цикла, что означает?

Tags: java, циклы

Есть цикл:

```
for (Contact cn : contacts)
```

что означает двоеточие и как записать в классическом виде?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это и есть классический вид цикла foreach.

Есть некий [итерируемый](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) объект (например, массив или коллекция) `contacts`, в которой элементы имеют тип `Contact` (или могут быть к нему приведены). Для каждого элемента выполняется тело цикла, в котором он имеет имя `cn`.

Comment: точнее некоторые сущности, реализующие интерфейс [Iterable<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)

Comment: @Nikita, спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Это так называемый цикл, основанный на диапазоне (range-based loop). Классический эквивалент:

```
for (i = 0; i < contacts.size(); ++i)
{
    Contact cn = contacts[i]
    ...
}
```

Comment: Этот код верен только если `contacts` - массив.

Comment: @Qwertiy, на самом деле он не верен, будь `contacts` массивом или списком. Если массив, то длина его `ARRAY.lenght`, если `List`, то надо элемент через `LIST.get(i)` получать. Ни туда ни сюда получается)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, я про get подумал, а про length забыл)))

Comment: Всем спасибо! Я понял смысл и уже использую это.